# Creating RDD from input data with repeated delimiters - Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have input data as key value pairs with pipe delimitation as below, some of values contain delimiters in its fields.

```
key1:value1|key2:val:ue2|key3:valu||e3  
key1:value4|key2:value5|key3:value6
```

Expected output is below.

```
value1|val:ue2|valu||e3   
value4|value5|value6
```

i tried as below to create RDD,

```
rdd=sc.textFile("path").map(lambda l: [x.split(":")[1] for x in l.split("|")]).map(tuple)
```

Above mapping works when we don't have these delimiters in the input value fields as below.

```
key1:value1|key2:value2|key3:value3  
key1:value4|key2:value5|key3:value6
```

And also i tried regex as below,

```
rdd=sc.textFile("path").map(lambda l: [x.split(":")[1] for x in l.split("((?<!\|)\|(?!\|))")]).map(tuple)
```

Input data without delimiters

```
key1:value1|key2:value2|key3:value3  
key1:value4|key2:value5|key3:value6  
>>> rdd=sc.textFile("testcwp").map(lambda l: [x.split(":")[1] for x in l.split("|")])
>>> rdd.collect()
[(u'value1', u'value2', u'value3'), (u'value4', u'value5', u'value6')]
```

Input data with delimiters

```
key1:value1|key2:val:ue2|key3:valu||e3  
key1:value4|key2:value5|key3:value6  
Without regex
>>> rdd=sc.textFile("testcwp").map(lambda l: [x.split(":")[1] for x in l.split("|")]).map(tuple)
>>> rdd.collect()
Error: IndexError: list index out of range
```

with regex

```
>>> rdd=sc.textFile("testcwp").map(lambda l: [x.split(":")[1] for x in l.split("((?<!\|)\|(?!\|))")).map(tuple)
>>> rdd.collect()
[(u'value1|key2'), (u'value4|key2')]
```

How can i achieve below result from the input?

```
[(u'value1', u'val:ue2', u'valu||e3'), (u'value4', u'value5', u'value6')]
```

From this i will create dataframe do some processing.

Any suggestions from pure python also welcome. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Is there any chnace you can convert it and try with JSON format

Comment: The input data I'm getting is in this format only.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

The main issue is l.split() works for fixed delimiter only.

```
rdd=sc.textFile("testcwp").map(lambda l: [x.split(":")[1:] for x in re.split("((?<!\|)\|(?!\|))",l)]).map(tuple)
>>> rdd.collect()
[([u'value1'], [u'val', u'ue2'], [u'val||ue3']), ([u'value4'], [u'value5'], [u'value6'])]
```

Following RDD concatenates elements inside lists,

```
>>> rdd2=rdd.map(lambda l: ['|'.join(x) for x in l]).map(tuple)
>>> rdd2.collect()
[(u'value1', u'value2', u'val||ue3'), (u'value4', u'value5', u'value6')]
```